# Yara Rules not matching a String - Windows Event

Tags: python, powershell, logging, event-viewer, yara

I need a little help:
I was triggering "Registry persistence" events which can be related to a malware presence.

Here is the Yara rule I tried to get triggered from Sysmon events (Event Viewer channel)

```
rule RegistryPersistence
{
         strings:
                      $CommandLine = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce"
         condition:
                      $CommandLine
}
```

Here is the powershell command I want to trigger:

> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v 0 /d C:\temp\malicious.dll

I did tried to use  "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce*" but nothing changed.
However if I specify $CommandLine = "reg.exe" I'll get the event triggered as expected.

Any help would be really appreciated in this moment.

The event from the Event Viewer is

> Process Create: RuleName: - UtcTime: 2023-04-24 21:07:52.827
> ProcessGuid: {f3ae464f-efa8-6446-1104-000000000e00} ProcessId: 11916
> Image: C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe FileVersion: 10.0.17763.1
> (WinBuild.160101.0800) Description: Registry Console Tool Product:
> Microsoft® Windows® Operating System Company: Microsoft Corporation
> OriginalFileName: reg.exe CommandLine: "C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe"
> add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v 0 /d
> C:\temp\malicious.dll CurrentDirectory: C:\Windows\system32\ User:
> DESKTOP-D577HXY\Tester LogonGuid:
> {f3ae464f-df1a-6446-3085-c10000000000} LogonId: 0xC18530
> TerminalSessionId: 1 IntegrityLevel: High Hashes:
> SHA256=19316D4266D0B776D9B2A05D5903D8CBC8F0EA1520E9C2A7E6D5960B6FA4DCAF
> ParentProcessGuid: {f3ae464f-df1b-6446-4c03-000000000e00}
> ParentProcessId: 10264 ParentImage:
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> ParentCommandLine:
> "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
> ParentUser: DESKTOP-D577HXY\Tester

Answer (score 0):

You need to use modifiers next to string value variable, something like:

- fullword
- ascii
- nocase
- wide

I suggest you to use:

`$CommandLine = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce` wide ascii

So, try to run

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).